# Clustering based on location and time

Tags: time, geolocation, location, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis

I am trying to figure out whether I am home, at university or somewhere else based on gps coordinates and timestamps.

For example: I have some entries at the same locations at 8:00, 9:00 and so on, and at 12:00 location changes -> so 8-14 should be classified as school time and that location should be marked as university place.

My questions is: what do I need to achieve this?
Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks

Edit: I want to do this in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use classification, not clustering. "University" is not something a clustering will output.

Also, do you need time?

Just label with a nearby known coordinate. Home ± x is home, university ±y (with probably a larger y, or maybe multiple locations is university.

Comment: Yes, I need time. Assuming I don't know what are the coordinates for home, I need to classify a geoposition as home based on time ( for example: some entries from 20:00 till 7:00 next day whould mean that position should be marked as home)

Comment: Could I use DBSCAN to achieve this ?

Comment: Probably you could cluster the data with DBSCAN and then label the cluster based on the predominant time. But parameterization may be difficult, I'd rather use OPTICS or HDBSCAN.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it. Thanks a lot